# How are character arrays stored in memory?

Tags: c++

I've written a `.cpp` file with simple code. In the `main()` function, I defined a variable:

```cpp
unsigned char data[18210] = { 0x3A, 0x12, 0x12, /* ... */ };
```

[image]

I have initialized it with 18210 bytes. What I expect is that all 18210 bytes may be contiguously stored somewhere, or divided into a few parts but still contiguously.

I checked the raw data of the `.exe` file that is compiled from the above `.cpp` file. I found that only one byte is recorded in eight bytes, and other bytes look like serial numbers.

In the first picture below, I've marked some bytes at the beginning of the variable data. The second picture also shows the bytes stored in memory, but those two parts of the byte storage arrangement are not the same.

[image: first picture]

[image: second picture]

It is not efficient, so I want to know how this occurs although it is useful for me.

Comment: Perhaps you're not looking at the right data? It could just be some other part of the executable file?

Comment: the first link is the second picture and the second picture is the first picture

Comment: Does this problem occur when the array is smaller? Can you reduce the size to a small number, and then post a complete program here that demonstrates the problem? (See [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).)

Comment: i checked for more than 100 bytes, it have similar arrangement, i'm sure  its right

Comment: when array is smaller , the array will stored continuous as we expect. i have found the raw data of a structure in the exe file and the structure's total size maybe less than 100 bytes in the past.

Comment: i wrote another program just now. all the code is int main() {unsigned char hexData[18159] = {};} i left out the specific bytes. i'm confused that the size of the generated exe file is certainly 152kb.

Comment: All arrays in C++ are always stored contiguously, no ifs or buts. Full stop, end of story.

Comment: but how to explain the picture above? i think you can write a similar test program and check the size of exe file

Comment: I have no idea what the picture above shows. There are some numbers and some characters which I cannot interpret. Here's how this site works:  *you* write a test program, *you* post it here in its entirety, *you* show the command *you* use to compile it, and *you* show how *you* extract data from the executable. Once you do that, I can repeat your exact steps and reproduce (or not) your results.

Comment: 0x3A, 0x12, 0x12, 0x12, 0x12, 0x49, 0x59, 0x99, 0xDA, 0xE8, 0x52, 0xB9, 0x76, 0x2F, 0x59, 0x91, 0xD2, 0x3D, 0x5C, 0x12, 0x12, 0x51, 0xE9, 0x1D, 0x12, 0x12, 0x12, 0x4C, 0x5A, 0x99, 0x3C, 0x5A, 0x9F, 0x3E, 0x22, 0x5A, 0x9F, 0x26, 0x62, 0x5A, 0x99, 0x46, 0x7E, 0x72, 0x5A, 0x91, 0xD1, 0x3D, 0x18, 0x12, 0x12, 0xDB, 0x5E, 0x7E, 0x7A, 0x11, 0x12, 0x12, 0x12, 0x3A, 0x1D, 0x12, 0x12, 0x12, 0x5A, 0x99, 0x2E, 0xB4, 0xDF, 0x5A, 0x87, 0xDE, 0x5A, 0x99, 0x4A, 0x1A, 0x5E, 0x99, 0x5A, 0x72, 0x46, 0x99, 0x52, 0x0A, 0x99, 0x42, 0x02, 0x4D, 0x4C, 0x4B, 0x51, 0x4E, 0x51, 0x4D, 0x51, 0x4C, this is raw data

Comment: One possible but unlikely explanation is that you are looking at the code segment and the compiler generates machine code to copy them byte by byte to fill the array on the stack. The extra bits are machine codes for the instruction. Although I don't think a sane compiler would do that.

Comment: Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/1KajKhjs8. Note that 1. I'm using GCC5, an ancient compiler. 2. The machine code is not exactly the same as you showed, but follows the  same pattern. I can write an answer if you want.

Comment: It is a non static local variable, 
so the compiler should fill the variable at runtime, 
godbolt show this compiler use one move assembly instruction  by array element, each move instruction use 7 bytes.

It is not code memory space efficient.
You can improve this by writing :

static const unsigned char tconst[18210] = { 0x3A, 0x1...};
unsigned char data[18210];
std::copy(std::begin(data), std::end(data), tconst);

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I didn't understand why it takes so much memory at first, but now I find this way is more suitable for my program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like my wild guess in the comments is correct, so I'm turning it into an answer.

What you are looking at is the code segment (confirmed by OP). The compiler is generating the machine code to push the bytes one by one onto the stack. Each byte is part of its own machine code.

Take the second screenshot as an example, you have observed the pattern

```
c6 44 24 34 [12]
c6 44 24 35 [49]
c6 44 24 36 [59]
```

where the bytes in the square bracket are the bytes in the target char array. Now, using any disassembly tool, for example [this one online](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm), we can find that in x86 and x86_64,

```
c6 44 24 34 12
```

disassembles to (in Intel assembly syntax)

```
mov    BYTE PTR [?sp+0x34],0x12
```

where `?sp` is `esp` for x86 and `rsp` for x86_64. Following this pattern, we can now see that each group of five bytes correspond to a `mov` instruction which fills the array on stack with the bytes of interest.

Admittedly, this is not a very efficient way in terms of the size of the executable. However, old compilers do do that, as I demonstrated in the [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/1KajKhjs8) which compiles a similar code using gcc5. Newer compilers like gcc13 do saner things by filling multiple bytes a time even with optimization turned off, but still for stack array the bytes are encoded in the code segment, just that fewer `mov` instructions are used.

Finally, for those who cannot read Chinese, the Chinese texts in the upper right corners of the screenshots translate to "Corresponding texts". The garbled texts directly below them result from the interpretation of the executable's bytes as Windows CP1252 encoded characters.

Answer (score 1):

Weijun Zhou might be right.. Maybe your structure is constructed somehow on the stack. You could try to mark your Array as *static const* to ensure that it will be placed in a data section you can read with the object dump **objdump** tool.
In addition you should generate a map of object placement. Pass „-Wl,-Map=output.map“ to GCC. This will generate a map file where object symbols and their addresses are listed.
If your structure shows up here only then you can find it in your program.

Answer (score 0):

You could be looking at UTF-32 encoding, 32-bits (4 bytes) containing one character.  Search the internet for "Unicode UTF32 character encoding".

Although you may be able to get away with only 1 byte per encoding, the compiler has decided (or was told to) use 4 bytes per encoding.  By definition of an array, all slots in an array must be the same size (type).  So, it's probably best that if you have one 32-bit encoding to make all the slots 32-bit.

You could also be using UTF-8 encoding.  The UTF-8 encoding is variable length to a maximum of 24 bits.  Since with an array, all slots must be the same size, they would be 24 bits, to handle the maximum encoding size for UTF-8.  24-bits is not a nice number, so the compiler rounds the size up to 32-bits (many processors fetch 32-bits at a time anyway).

Comment: not encoding, i checked the raw data and those bytes do exist in code segment as Weijun Zhou says.